# How likely is it that valid results of AES decryption differ in one byte and only one byte?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need to decrypt AES encrypted bytes in Java. The source data begins with 2 known verification bytes as an indication of successful decryption. The length of the data is less than 255 bytes for some protocol reasons and the data is assumed to be padded if needed by whoever encrypts the data already, with the same verification bytes mentioned before used as padding. I have successfully decrypted hundreds of thousands of records with my available approach.

Now I get some records which after successful(?) decryption differ in ONE AND ONLY ONE byte to what is expected as the decrypted result. Of course it's not the verification bytes ;-), but some other one byte with a very special, documented meaning. And it is ALWAYS the same byte with ALWAYS the same, constant wrong value. It's simply that I e.g. get a `0x47` where I should have `0x44` according to some manufacturer specific documentation.

Simple as that, everything else in the result is correct according to the documentation I have and makes sense. The problem now is that the manufacturer of the data I get claims to really get `0x44` instead of my `0x47` with the exact same input data. Differing opinions we have...

For the decryption I use [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) with `AES/CBC/NoPadding` and in the debugger of my application I can see that after the call to [Cipher.final](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer)) I already have the wrong `0x47` in my result data. Because I don't find any error in my approach, I decided to test alternative AES decrypters and found 3(!) different implementations claiming the exact same results I have for the exact same input data:

- http://aes.online-domain-tools.com
- http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc/index
- openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -iv "..." -K "..." -p -nopad -in in.bin -out out.bin

There are other AES decrypters out there, but most of them don't provide support for an init vector and therefore don't provide correct results. And that's the whole point, differing input produces differing output and the difference is always huge according to my tests. It's never only some few bytes changed or whatever, it is always completely wrong or completely correct, with the exception of the one byte I see.

So, can one and the same input for the same AES decryption operation produce different results, if proper AES is implemented? I don't think so.

How likely is it that wrong input produces correct results, except for one byte? Because either mine or the other input could simply be wrong, even though it's copied and I don't see any difference.

How likely is it that a wrong AES implementation produces nearly correct results? How likely is it, that Java provides a wrong AES implementation at all? I don't think so.

Any tips on what I could test any further? To me it looks like I have possibly 3 different additional implementations all proving my results, so I think what I'm doing is correct and the difference in the one special byte needs to come from somewhere else for some reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it appears that the incorrect byte is in the first block and thus caused by an incorrect IV.

Extending on the answer comment:

The IV is xor'ed with the first block of data, see [CBC mode decryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29). On encryption a single byte (or bit) change of the IV would affect all bytes but on decryption it only affect the bytes (bits) in the first block that correspond to the incorrect in byte (or bits) the IV.

Another common approach is to prepend the IV to the encrypted data, that avoids having to share the IV via another channel/method ensuring it is correct.

This does point out that the verification scheme is poor. A better scheme takes into account all the encrypted bytes, generally an HMAC of the encrypted data. But in a computationally limited environment a CRC or even checksum might be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

> How likely is it that wrong input produces correct results, except for one byte?

It might be very likely, depending on the wrong input: I found the difference, it is ONE AND ONLY ONE byte in the init vector which is different and that difference makes ONLY ONE byte difference in the actual result.

The difference in the init vector comes from different understanding of the underlying spec which defines how to properly build the init vector. The data comes from some device which needs to include its version number in the data and the spec allows to include that version in two different places at the same time. For the current problematic records it is available in two different places, but with two different values as well. So I use the version number from the first place while the other party uses the version number from the second place and because both values differ, we get different init vectors and different results.

WTF?! :-)

Comment: The IV is xor'ed with the first block of data, see [CBC mode decryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).  You do not specify the encryption mode, I assume CBC mode. On encryption a single byte would affect all bytes but on decryption it only affect the bytes that are incorrect in the IV.

Answer (score 0):

In CBC mode, each cipher text block is decrypted, using the key, and then that result is XORed with the previous block of cipher text to recover the plain text.

Because this is a simple XOR operation, flipping bits in the previous cipher text will flip the corresponding bits in the current plain text block. (And, of course, decrypting data with flipped bits will also completely corrupt the previous block of plain text.)

There is no "previous" block of cipher text when decrypting the first block. That's where the initialization vector comes in. It acts as the zeroth block of cipher text, and as explained above, changes to the IV will cause bit-for-bit changes in the first plain text block.